# DataGridTextColumn tooltip issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this style to add a tooltip to a cell in each row of a datagrid. The problem is that all the tooltips have the same text (the text of the first row). What am I doing wrong?

```
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Profit (%)"
                            Binding="{Binding Percentage, StringFormat=N8}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"
                       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip.ContentTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ToolTip.ContentTemplate>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

But if I use a simple tooltip, it works perfect

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Profit (%)"
                    Binding="{Binding Percentage, StringFormat=N8}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding Percentage}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `ContentTemplate` and set the `Tooltip` to a `TextBlock` that binds to the parent `DataGridCell`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.Content.Text, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}" />
                </ToolTip>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```